# How to restart a Python script on all platforms?

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyqt, subprocess

I have a script which needs to reload to update its contents. I have to reload the script to satisfy Qt, as it cannot delete widgets perfectly and then create new widgets at the same place.

`os.execv` and `os.execl` work fine on Linux but not on Windows. Please provide a solution that either works on all platforms or just Windows, to serve my purpose.

Comment: On Windows, `os.execv` can't work the same as on Unix. The original process has to exit because there's no Windows API to execute a program in an existing process. For example, if it's a console app run from cmd.exe or it's run in a batch script, then cmd sees that your process exited and resumes. It doesn't know about the `execv` child process. Instead, you can you close all of your Qt windows, respawn your script with the original command-line arguments using `subprocess.call` and `sys.executable`, and wait on the child process to proxy its exit code.

Comment: Your claims about deleting widgets are completely false. Reloading the script is an hack, not a solution. If are having problems deleting widgets, you should provide some example code that demonstrates that.

Comment: I've made a hack. Created a QFrame which has the contents in grid layout. When refresh is required, all widgets in the grid layout are deleted and then the frame is repopulated.